# Disable links on Forum Containers

Tags: 8, nodes

Using Drupal 8, is there a way to disable the links of the Forum Containers on the Index Page of the Forum (Forum is activated via the Forum core Module)?

Comment: Could'nt you hide them with css?

Comment: I want to display them as "Titles", I just don't want them to link to anything.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery, like this:

```
$(".link-class").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```